# Roles and analysis of results Excel Surveys

Tags: excel, survey, roles

I have a excel survey created in a SharePoint page. Right now if I share the link, anyone can fill in the survey. Can I somehow restricted so that only users with an account on the intranet, or certain groups of users in your organization can fill? And what a user can do it only once? And my other question is, if you can do something with the results, for example by SharePoint work flows, for example, display data in an easier format to display excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Survey from an Excel Survey to a SharePoint Survey

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba

where all your requirements can be set.

If you do fancy Excel stuff you have to replicate that with SharePoint Views, maybe add some Calculated Columns.
Or open your SharePoint survey data in Excel again.

Take some days to play with SharePoint Surveys and search Google a lot, plenty of blogs out there